# How to sustrack values when keys are the same in pairRDDs?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, keyvaluepair

I have two `pairRDDs` `(Int, BreezeDenseMatrix[Double])` and what i want is, when the `keys` are the same to substrack their values.

E.g. when i have

`RDD_1` : `(1, BreezeMatrix_a)`

`RDD_2`: `(1, BreezeMatrix_b)`

wanted result: `(1, BreezeMatrix_a-BreezeMatrix_b)`

I tried `join` but what is returned is `(Int, (BreezeMatrix_a, BreezeMatrix_b))` and i don't know how the second part could be transformed. I can't understand if it is a `set` or an `array`, `spark` is not clear to that.
Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the result of the join be

```
joinresult = (Int, (BreezeMatrix_a, BreezeMatrix_b))
```

then give

```
actualresult = joinresult.map( a => (a._1,( a._2_1 - a._2_2)))
```